# SQI and CQI values in Android

Tags: android, signals, gsm

I am developing an Android application for measuring the signal quality (not strength).
I would like to retrieve the SQI(Speech for both 2G and 3G) and CQI(HS Data for 3G only)

Does anyone have a clue how to measure these values or how to get the signal strength ?

SQI: Signal Quality Index
CQI: Channel Quality Indicator

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the same boat as you. Looking/researching for methods to obtain these values.
Well, as far as I've dig over documentations and web forums, I suppose that:

1. Android (and maybe any other device) do not have API to get these values. Only signal strength and other values related to signals that **incomes** the user device are available;
2. CQI is a value that **is not** received by the user device, but calculated inside it and sent to the towers (B-Nodes) for handover/recalculation purposes.
3. Different vendors have different manners to calculate CQI, and it seems to be out of standards (I suppose). At this moment, the most "standarized" CQI calculation that I've found can be seen in [Qualcomm Patent](http://www.faqs.org/patents/app/20120163207), a recurring polynomial-like formula described in the items [0066], [0068] and [0070] of the document;
4. I'm not sure of these informations. As we're working with state-of-the art technology, it is very hard to confirm any informations due to lack of documents;
5. Maybe, you can try an approach with AT Commands (I'm trying this right now...)

**UPDATE 28/01/2015:** I've traced a good part of AOSP telephony classes and haven't found any reference to CQI (other than AT command calls to **AT+CSQ** that is NOT the command that gives CQI) even in the Radio Interface Layer (Android RIL). Based on my researches over AOSP tree and Android native libraries, I suspect that CQI is calculated in the PPP (Point-to-Point Protocol) L2 network layer, in the context of LQR (Link Quality Report). For those who want to take a look too, I recommend to check AOSP native classes.

Comment: yes documentation is very bad and no enough info on this topic . but are you sure that CQI is calculated differently

Comment: As I've said, I'm not sure. I'm just basing my assumptions above previously read docs and forums. So, may you find updated/good informations, please make a reply :)

Comment: ok thank you for your answer :) sure I'll share any info I know